Picking from a categorical distribution such that the selection is stable
Let's say I have a random variable $V$ which takes values from the finite set $V = \{v_1, v_2,...,v_N \}$. I want to pick one value randomly based on given probabilities $p_i = \Pr(V=v_i)$. Let's call this value $v^*$. This by itself is an easy task. However, I want my random selection to be "stable" (defined below) as much as possible if the probability values $p_i$ (for $i=1,..,N$) change slightly to $p'_i$. To explain what I mean by "stable", first assume there is a notion of distance defined between different values in $V$, denoted by $d(v_i,v_j)$. Given this distance, I want my random selection to be stable in the following sense: when the probability values change slightly from $p_i$ to $p'_i$, and then I make a new random selection ${v^*}'$ based on $p'_i$, I want my new selection ${v^*}'$ to be close to $v^*$ as much as possible, as defined by the distance measure $d(v,v^*)$.
I understand that this is not a totally well-defined requirement. I just want to achieve this goal as much as possible using a not-so-complicated algorithm.
Example: As an example of a case where I have a solution is when I can sort $V$ values on a line. For simplicity, let's assume they are already sorted:
$$\text{For }i=1,...,N-1: v_i < v_{i+1}.$$
Then I calculate the cumulative probabilities:
$$
c_0 = 0\\
c_j = \sum_{i=1}^j p_i.
$$ Then I pick a seeded random number $x$ uniformly between 0 and 1. Then I pick $v^*=v_j$ such that
$$
c_{j-1} \le x < c_{j}.
$$
We can see that when the values $p_i$ change slightly, the selected index $j'$ is likely to be close to $j$.
However, I don't know how to solve the problem when the $V$ have a more complex relationship to each other (more complex topological structure I guess). For example, when they live on a higher dimensional lattice.

Are you able to give a simple example where it is possible to do better than a trivial solution?

If by trivial solution you mean when $V$ values have a 1-d structure, then no; I don't have an example solution for more complex cases.
